# data-toggle="tab" and Anchor Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't get the anchor Tag helper to work in combination with data-toggle = tag.

I manage to set the active class on the correct tab but my code on my controller will never be run. What am I missing?

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Device" asp-fragment="PlantInfo" data-toggle="tab" >Enhetsinformation</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Start" data-toggle="tab" >Larm</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Start" data-toggle="tab" >Historik</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="MeterReading" asp-fragment="MeterReading" data-toggle="tab" >Avläsningar</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Start" data-toggle="tab" >Ärenden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs are not really supposed to actually hit your controller. The whole point is that you're switching between content *on page*. The Bootstrap tab javascript is going to prevent the default action of the link such that it doesn't actually take you to a new page, but just loads the reference content area. That's also why the actual href of your tab links should be targets, point to the ids of the various content areas on your page:

```
<a href="#content1" data-toggle="tab">Content 1</a>
...
<div id="content1">
    Tab content
</div>
```

If I had to guess at your confusion here, I'd imagine you're thinking that by linking to an actual controller action, that content should be fetched from the server and rendered on the page when you click that tab. That's incorrect and not how Bootstrap tabs work. If you wanted it to function that way, you'd need your own JavaScript to define the tab switching behavior (Bootstrap's code will not work anymore for this) and as part of that, you'd need to issue AJAX requests to fetch that content. That's all on you. It doesn't happen automatically.